# Getting Extra String value from a previous Activity inside an onClick method

Tags: android

my Class implements an onClickListener, so I did this:

onCreate:

```
   final ImageButton btn_audio = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btn_tool_audio);
                    btn_audio.setOnClickListener(this);
```

onClick method:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()){
          case R.id.btn_tool_audio:
              Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
          String audio_text_url = extras.getString("audio_text_url");
              Intent launchAudio= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, audio_text_url);
              startActivity(launchAudio);
               break;
```

but then the value of the String is 'null', the question is how am I able to get its value from the previous activity inside an onClick method?

FYI I don't have any problem in getting the value when I call the extra inside onCreate

Comment: show us the code where you are setting values in bundle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to refernce the String of the extras in onCreate to a member and use it later?

```
private String _saveMe;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   _saveMe = getIntent().getExtras().getString("audio_text_url");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use

```
Bundle extras = YOURCURRENTACTVITY.this.getIntent().getExtras();
```

instead of

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps get the bundle out from *onCreate* and use it later.

```
Bundle bndl = null;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   ...
   ...
   bndl = getIntent().getExtras();
}


@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()){
          case R.id.btn_tool_audio:

          String audio_text_url = bndl.getString("audio_text_url");
              Intent launchAudio= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, audio_text_url);
              startActivity(launchAudio);
               break;
```