# Starting activity from outside application, missing extras

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I've got a widget in my application from which it should be possible to the application using `startActivity()` and I need to also pass along some extras with the `Intent` starting the activity. But in `onCreate()` the `Bundle`'s are null!?!
Have tried to figure this out and someone has solved this by overriding `onNewIntent()` as this could be called if an instance of my activity already exists, but no success in this either as `onNewIntent()` never gets called. So what's happening here? I just want to start an activity from outside my application and pass some extras with the `Intent`?

```
Intent intent= new Intent(context, SmsAlarm.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.putExtra(SWITCH_FRAGMENT_REQUEST, true);

context.startActivity(intent);
```

As I told earlier, my activity starts fine this way but I loose my extras, which I need. Can anyone tell me whats and why this happens.

Comment: you **are** trying to get the intent with `getIntent()` and its extras with `getIntent().getExtras()` instead of the `savedInstanceState` bundle, right?

Comment: how do you read the SWITCH_FRAGMENT_REQUEST  value ?

Comment: Post the code where you are trying to receive the extras

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way to open an Activity intent from the widget is to use [PendingIntent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html). You should not have any issues when doing that.

Setting up the **PendingIntent** as described in the [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html):

```
// Create an Intent to launch ExampleActivity
Intent intent = new Intent(context, ExampleActivity.class);
// Add Extra
intent.putExtra("MY_EXTRA", "extra");

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

// Get the layout for the App Widget and attach an on-click listener
// to the button
RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.appwidget_provider_layout);
views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button, pendingIntent);
```

Now, get the extra as you normally would:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    mMyExtra = extras.getString("MY_EXTRA", null);
}
```

**MY_EXTRA** should be a const somewhere.

Comment: Nice short, informative answer. Worked like a charm this way!

Answer (score 0):

Check this link.
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299461/getting-extra-string-value-from-a-previous-activity-inside-an-onclick-method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

To the other Activity, in onCreate method for take a string you must use

```
saveMe = getIntent().getExtras().getString("string");
```

If you have a boolean you can use

```
boolean defaultValue = false;
boolean yourValue = getIntent().getBooleanExtra(YOUR_EXTRA, defaultValue);
```

To Developer.android

[Intent Developer.android](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)